# Need help on concept for database with kind of recursive data

Tags: mysql

I have data which describes maintain specifications for devices. To make it easy lets say I get the following specs from the global engineering team:

Device A: Needs 3 maintain jobs a year

Device B: Needs 4 maintain jobs a year

Device C: Needs 5 maintain jobs a year

Device D: Needs 6 maintain jobs a year

Now it is possible that a Pole like EMEA (Europe/Middle East/Africa) is changing some of this specs to fulfill their legal rights. eg.

Device A: Needs 3 maintain jobs a year

Device B: Needs 2 maintain jobs a year

Device C: Needs 4 maintain jobs a year

Device D: Needs 6 maintain jobs a year

Not enough, Germany will also have some changes depending on the changes EMEA did:

Device A: Needs 3 maintain jobs a year

Device B: Needs 2 maintain jobs a year

Device C: Needs 1 maintain jobs a year

Device D: Needs 6 maintain jobs a year

This can lead further to county, city etc. So it would be a good idea to make it endless and not fix in layers.

To store the connecting data I thought I will setup two tables like

```
table stages
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
name VARCHAR(100)

table stagetypes
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
name INT
stage INT
priority INT
```

which will hold the entries

```
table stages
1 Global
2 EMEA
3 Germany
4 Bavaria
5 Munich

table stagetypes
1 1 null 0 // Global setup on nothing priority 0
2 2 2    1 // EMEA setup on EMEA priority 1
3 2 1    0 // EMEA setup on Global priority 0
4 3 3    2 // Germany setup on Germany priority 2
5 3 2    1 // Germany setup on EMEA priority 1
6 3 1    0 // Germany setup on Global priority 0
```

With this tables I can easily query the needed stages for a given stage. Lets say for Germany I can get all needed stages with

```
SELECT sstage.stage 
FROM stagetypes
JOIN stages AS mstage ON (stage.id = stagetypes.name)
JOIN stages AS stage ON (stage.id = stagetypes.stage)
WHERE mstage.name = 'Germany'
ORDER BY stagetypes.priority DESC
```

Result will be an array with

Germany, EMEA, Global

So far so good.

Now I can create a specification table:

```
table specs
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
device VARCHAR(100)
numberofvisits INT
stage INT
```

and fill it with data like

```
table specs
1 DeviceA 3 1
2 DeviceB 4 1
3 DeviceC 5 1
4 DeviceD 6 1
5 DeviceB 2 2 // Change for EMEA
6 DeviceC 4 2 // Change for EMEA
7 DeviceC 1 3 // Change for Germany
```

But now I have no idea how to fetch the specs for Germany of all Devices.

Result should be

```
1 DeviceA 3 1
4 DeviceD 6 1
5 DeviceB 2 2
7 DeviceC 1 3
```

So how can I design the specs table to get this data with a most simple query? Or do you have a complete different approach to solve this problem?

At the end I am restricted to use mySQL5.7 or OracleSQL11. So ranking is not a possible solution :(

Comment: At the end I am not really fixed on a specific sql language and I don't think this is really important for the general design. I can use oracle sql (which has no tag here at all) also a mysql or in worse case also mssql. But I have added mySQL because I guess this is what the most people can help with

Comment: You have me lost somewhere. I see that per device there can be global setup and possibly an EMEA setup and maybe even a German setup, etc. Then you rank Germany higher then EMEA and EMEA higher than global. So you take the German setup if it exists, else the EMA setup if it exists, else the global setup. I don't understand "EMEA setup on EMEA", "EMEA setup on Global", though. I would have thought there is a table of the teams (Global etc.) each with their priority (Global = lowest, etc.) and you use this to decide wich setup ranks highest for a device. Am I missing something?

Comment: I setup EMEA on EMEA to also get EMEA as a stage if I query for EMEA. If I only setup EMEA on Global I will only get Global as query result. Of course I could also just query Global and add EMEA manually because I know its part of the result.

Comment: Is a 'pole' the same as a 'stage'?

Comment: Problem is that I do not know the right wording at all. For me I have Global/Pole/Country/County/City for which I needed a generic term and choose stage. A Pole is a political or economical group of countries. So we have EMEA like explained. LATAM = Latein America, Mexico, APAC = Asia and Pacific Countries and some more.

Answer (score 1):

Ranking rows in a modern DBMS (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL starting with version 8, SQL Server, etc.) is very easy with the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

If the data model were this:

### institutions

```
+----------------+---------+----------+
| institution_id |  name   | priority |
+----------------+---------+----------+
|              1 | Global  |        0 |
|              2 | EMEA    |        1 |
|              3 | Germany |        2 |
+----------------+---------+----------+
```

### setups

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| device_id | instituion_id | job_count |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| A         |             1 |         3 |
| B         |             1 |         4 |
| C         |             1 |         5 |
| A         |             2 |         3 |
| B         |             2 |         2 |
| A         |             3 |         3 |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

then you'd select the most relevant setup per device as follows:

```
select *
from setups s
join institutions i using (instituion_id)
order by row_number() over (partition by s.device_id order by i.priority desc)
fetch first rows with ties;
```

(This is standard SQL syntax and should work in Oracle and PostgreSQL. For SQL Server and MySQL you'd write the query a little different.)

Using an old DBMS such as MySQL 5 just makes writing the query a tad more clumsy, that's all. Here is a solution with `NOT EXIST` (get the setups where not exists a better setup for the device):

```
select *
from setups s
join institutions i using (instituion_id)
where not exists
(
  select null
  from setups sx
  join institutions ix using (instituion_id)
  where sx.device_id = s.device_id
  and ix.priority > i.priority
);
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but my fault. I have multiple SQL solutions but all are not up to date (Yes I know bad but not my fault. Its a big company which is very slow in accepting modern technology because of security reasons). So ranking functions are not available for me. I guess I will edit my post to require mysql5.7

Comment: No big deal. Of course you can rank rows in an older DBMS, too. I've added a solution for this.

Comment: Oracle 11g supports `ROW_NUMBER` by the way. It doesn't support the `FETCH` clause, though. In Oracle 11g use the query with `NOT EXISTS` or use `ROW_NUMBER` in a subquery (aka derived table) and only keep the rows ranked #1.

Comment: Thx a lot. I will try ASAP and report